# Can't load the Canvas module in Node.js in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js

I haven't been able to load the Canvas module into my Node.js application. When I include the line

```
const Canvas = require('canvas');
```

I end up getting the error:

```
module.js:681
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: /home/artezanz/Documents/Developer/Discord/sun-qiang/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: undefined symbol: _ZN5Image5errorEN2v85LocalINS0_5ValueEEE
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/artezanz/Documents/Developer/Discord/sun-qiang/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

For reference, I'm working on Ubuntu, with version `6.1.0` of npm and `v8.11.3` of Node.js (the LTS version). Do I need to switch to the latest version of Node to be able to use the Canvas library?

Let me know if there's any additional information needed.